# How to stop LWA_COLORKEY from making a gray outline?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, transparent

I am making a kill-counter for a game I play.
I am doing this by covering the game with a transparent window. I got the window transparent, however, when I use `SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(255, 255, 255), 255, 0x01);` it outlines the transparent window in a gray box, which is very annoying.

How would I stop it from doing that?
I can't use `SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hWnd, RGB(255, 255, 255), 0, 0x02);` because it hides everything I draw on it.

Comment: On a side note, don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). The [`SetLayeredWindowAttributes()]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setlayeredwindowattributes) API has human-readable constants defined, where `0x01` is `LWA_COLORKEY` and `0x02` is `LWA_ALPHA`, use these instead. Same with any other Win32 API that uses flag values as parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, all I had to do was add WS_POPUPWINDOW to my window styles.